# Completing a Metric Space of Cauchy Sequences.

Tags: analysis

On the internet, I found a brief paper by Brent Nelson that is almost expansive enough for me to understand.  Still, I am misunderstanding something in trying to show that the i map from constant Cauchy sequences (CS) to the metric space (ms) of equivalence classes (ec) is dense in the latter.
I start with an ec and try to show that in its neighborhood, no matter how small, there is always to be found a meeting with the i mapping.  I look at the metric from the ec to the ec of a constant CS and see that the metric always converges, because the "distance" between two CSs has a limit.   How can I construct a constant CS that will work for an arbitrarily chosen ec's representative whose distance will be epsilon?

Comment: Given any Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$, consider the sequence of constant sequences $y_n(i)=x_n$, i.e., $y_n$ is the constant sequence taking value $x_n$. Why does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_1, x_2, ...).$ We wish to show that there is a point $y$ so that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} d(x_i, y) < \epsilon,$$
for $\epsilon > 0$ any given number.

But $\{x_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy. So there's $N$ large so that if $n, m > N$ then $d(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon/17.$ Set $y = x_{N+1}.$ Then you have the desired limit, and hence any small neighborhood of the equivalence class of your starting Cauchy sequence always contains a constant Cauchy sequence.